# Which versions of Mathematica work on macOS Ventura?

Tags: mac-os-x, compatibility

Which versions of Mathematica work on macOS 13 (Ventura)?  Does Mathematica 12.0 work on this OS?  If yes, I assume all later versions work as well.  I know that pre-12 versions do not, as they require 32-bit support.

Comment: I am using `Ventura 13.0.1` and `12.0.0` is working fine-the 64-bit that is. I mean it in the sense that I have not noticed any issues hitherto.

Comment: @bmf Thank you! Could you post that as an answer? Others who are looking to upgrade to Ventura but need old M versions may find this useful as well.

Comment: Just did. Probably the easiest one I have written. I am quite happy to be honest :D

Comment: @bmf Thanks! I was concerned because of https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62295780#62295780

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up, because I just remembered that I should have clarified the chip as well.

Comment: @bmf Hm, I thought 12.0 does not have native Apple Silicon support, does it? Are you running it on Rosetta?

Comment: Sorry, this is the comment I have been trying to write: As a matter of fact, when I bought the laptop the first thing I did was to install Rosetta to avoid any potential headaches, but it runs without it as well - I think https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/system-requirements.html. Even after the update there should not be any issues. But the right version has to be chosen.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Ventura `13.0.1` and `12.0.0` is working fine-the 64-bit that is.
I mean it in the sense that I have not noticed any issues hitherto.

Edit: this is taking the latest comment by @Szabolcs into consideration. I am using a macbook with the Apple M1 chip. I am unsure if there are any issues with Intel chips.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62295780#62295780, mathematica wasn't working at first after I upgraded to Ventura (macbook pro,13-inch, 2020, intel).
I tried my old install (12.1) and also installing 13.1, but both were not working: whenever I tried to launch the app, the launcher got stuck and I had to force-quit it.

I then noticed that it wasn't the case only for Mathematica, but also other programs were having the same problem (e.g. iMovie).

I didn't have much time to look into the problem, but then a couple of days ago I picked up my mac again, and everything was working fine (including both mathematica versions). I am not sure of what happened there, as I am not using that laptop much nowadays, possibly it had an automatic OS update that fixed the problem, but I am really not sure to be honest..